# What are some ways to be “fair” to multiple children with respect to college expenses?

Tags: education, money

I have three children and am heading into the college years. (This is in the United States.) I would like to treat them equally when it comes to providing for college education, but I can't define “equally” to my own satisfaction. I can predict that their educational expenses will be different:

- Different colleges have different costs
- Different kids might get different scholarships
- Travel expenses will be different between siblings

Some of those factors are directly under my children's control (e.g., deciding to go to a more expensive rather than a less expensive school), and some they can influence at least partially (e.g., having better grades and therefore better scholarships, being more diligent to apply for scholarships).

I'm also expecting that student loans will be needed.

Any number of difficult scenarios could arise. If I commit to making an equal financial contribution to each child, which seems fair, suppose one gets a full ride someplace? Do I just not have college expenses for that child, or should they get a sum of money for a down payment on a house or something?

I'm curious about different ways to think about this; I imagine there are different schools of thought. Here are two possibilities I can think of:

- Each child gets the same amount of money—whether they spend it on an expensive college or a house or a car.
- Each child gets through university either debt-free, or with the same amount of debt.

What are some other ways to think about this?

I posted this originally to Personal Finance & Money, and it was closed as opinion-based. In anticipation of a similar outcome here, I want to emphasize that I am not looking for a single way to think about this. A correct answer will give many different ways to think about this problem. (If I asked for the “best” way, then that would be opinion-based.)

Comment: A popular criterion is *need*, but you could instead consider who has done the most to *deserve* money. Who has worked the hardest, gotten the best grades, has the most potential? Then distribute the money accordingly. But be prepared for complaints.

Comment: I do think this question is quite opinion based, as you will see all 3 answers are different ...

Comment: @RoryAlsop People can always give opinions in answers, but the answer to the question I asked will be a list a different ways that people can think about the problem (i.e., different schools of thought, different factors to consider).

Comment: Fairness is subjective. As are these answers. Just because you asked for multiple opinions doesn't mean it's not opinion based.

Comment: And that’s _exactly_ what defines an opinion-based question. How could the community decide which one is better when all are correct?

Comment: @Stephie A correct answer is a complete list of opinions. An incorrect answer is an incomplete list of opinions. These sorts of questions are very common on other stack exchanges (e.g., "what are the arguments for...").

Answer (score 2):

You already mentioned equal money for everyone and equal money for the specific purpose of education/ college. Some other options to think about:

Your children are presumably not all the exact same age so will go through college at slightly different times. So it may be possible to use the same money multiple times and ask the oldest to pay back (some of) the money they received during college after they graduated to support the younger ones through college.

You could also consider the likely later income. A child studying something that will lead to a high paying job may be able to handle college debt much easier than a child studying something with unclear job prospects.

You could also differentiate your support by academic achievement and either support the smartest one most because they deserve it most or support the weakest one more because they need it more than the others.

Judging which of the options are fair is difficult and depends on a lot of circumstances so this is only meant as a list of possible options not an endorsement to use any particular one of them.

Comment: This is a great answer, +1. it also illustrates how very opinion oriented this question is.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, and the one we have gone for, with 3 children, is look at what they want to do.

One of mine is in final year of a sports degree, and wants to be a physio or coach. Another has a year and a half left of a cyber security degree, and wants to get into the infosec industry. And our third wants to tour the world in a camper van creating art.

So what is fair? The sport degree costs us the most, but we want our kids to be happy, healthy and in a career they can progress in. So we are fair in providing the basics (transport, food, accommodation costs) but know that we spend more on the sporting course than the cyber security course. And we are likely to spend far less on our third.

I think the outcomes are fair. For us. YMMV.

Comment: Another good example of how opinion-oriented this question is. This doesn't seem to me to be fair at all. But not much in life is fair, so there's that, and if your kids are happy with this distribution, it's the right choice for you. *It all depends.*

Answer (score 0):

【Opinion】

① There is the "even split" route of fairness, i.e. "You get this much money each. What you make of it is your responsibility as adults".

② Or the "equal opportunities" version of fairness. All humans are different, with different weaknesses and strengths, so we want to give everyone an equal chance at life.

Hard work shouldn't be penalized and putting one at a greater disadvantage should also be avoided, so perhaps a mix of both?

Split 70% of money evenly three ways, for tuition fees/down payments, etc. The last 30% could then be used as and when needed (months when they might financially struggle, rewards for achievements/graduations, textbooks, transportation fees for travelling home during a break etc.)